# Irreducibility of polynomials in two variables

Tags: polynomials, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. I am interested in sufficient criteria for $f \in k[x,y]$ to be irreducible. An example is Theorem A of this [paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa82/aa8237.pdf) (Brindza and Pintér, *On the irreducibility of some polynomials in two variables*, Acta Arith. 1997).

Does anyone know of similar results in the same vein? How about criteria over fields other than the complex numbers?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

A trick which works surprisingly often in my experience: If the Newton polytope of $f$ can not be written as a Minkowski sum of two smaller polytopes, then $f$ is irreducible. I think of this as a generalization of Eisenstein's criterion.

It is surprisingly easy to test whether a lattice polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as a Minkowski sum of smaller lattice polygon. Let $P$ be a lattice polytope. Travel around $\partial P$ and write down the vectors pointing from each lattice point to the next lattice point; call this sequence of vectors $v(P)$. For example, if our polynomial is $a y^2 + b y + c xy + d + e x + f x^2 + g x^3$, with $adg \neq 0$, then the lattice points on the boundary are $(0,2)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(3,0)$ so $v(P) =(\ (0,-1),\ (0,-1),\ (1,0),\ (1,0),\ (1,0),\ (-3,2)\ )$. (Note that $(1,1)$ is not on the boundary of the triangle.)

It turns out that $v(A + B)$ is simply the sequences $v(A)$ and $v(B)$, interleaved by sorting their slopes .  So, if $P$ can be written as the Minkowski sum $A+B$, we must be able to partition $v(P)$ into two disjoint sub-sequences, each of which sums to zero. In the above example, this can't be done, so any polynomial of the form $a y^2 + b y + c xy + d + e x + f x^2 + g x^3$, with $adg \neq 0$ is irreducible.

As an example of a polynomial which could factor, look at $a y^2 + by + c xy + dx + e x^2$. So the boundary is $(0,2)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$ with $v(P) = (\ (0,-1),\ (1,-1),\ (1,0),\ (-1,1),\ (-1, 1)\ )$. This is the interleaving of $(\ (0,-1),\  (1,0),\  (-1, 1)\ )$ and $(\ (1,-1),\ (-1,1)\ )$, so a polynomial with this Newton polytope could factor.

Comment: Thanks, that is probably close to what I want! Do you have a reference? And how to check decomposition of polytopes?  

Comment: I don't have a reference, but it is simple enough to see why: the Newton polytope of a product is the Minkowski sum of the convex hulls of the factors.

Comment: I'll edit the above to address your other question.

Comment: Brief remark: a+bx+cx2+dxy as above can also be seen to be irreducible in C[x,y] because it's (obviously) irreducible in C(x)[y], right? (and the coefficients, regarded as polys in x, are coprime in C[x], as a,d!=0).

Comment: Of course. It is a small example.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, as it works regardless of the fields and is quite elementary, which is close to what I wanted. Nice answers everyone, thanks. 

Comment: There have been repeated edits of the vectors in the example in this answer. But it doesn't make sense. How can there be four different differences when this polytope is a triangle, with only three edges? The people who edited this, can you please explain it, or correct your edits?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Does it work now?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, thank you!

Comment: Spoke too soon, I forgot I had returned to my original Newton polytope in the last pargraph. Now they are consistent with each other, although not with Kevin Buzzard's comment. I am afraid that, after 10 years, I no longer remember what polytope I originally intended.

Comment: Aargh, I made it worse and introduced a polynomial which actually can factor! I think it is right now.

Comment: didnt you miss the point $1,1$ in the first example (the irreducible one)? Since there is the term $cxy$

Comment: No, that's not on the boundary of the polygon!

Answer (score 92):

One of my all-time leading candidates for Most Preposterous Theorem Ever:

Definition: A polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is indecomposable if whenever $f(x) = g(h(x))$ for polynomials $g$, $h$, one of $g$ or $h$ is linear.

Theorem. Let $f, g$, be nonconstant indecomposable polynomials over $\mathbb C$. Suppose that $f(x)-g(y)$ factors in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Then either $g(x) = f(ax+b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, or
$$\operatorname{deg} f = \operatorname{deg} g = 7, 11, 13, 15, 21, \text{ or } 31,$$
and each of these possibilities does occur.

The proof uses the classification of the finite simple groups [!!!] and is due to Fried [1980, in the proceedings of the 1979 Santa Cruz conference on finite groups], following a the reduction of the problem to a group/Galois-theoretic statement by Cassels [1970]. [W. Feit, ["Some consequences of the classification of finite simple groups,"](http://books.google.com/books?id=UA-YqrL58dQC&lpg=PP1&ots=2I1C6mSw1t&dq=santa%20cruz%20conference%20finite%20groups&pg=PA176#v=snippet&q=indecomposable&f=false) 1980.]

Comment: Does it really?  I think I was assigned this as an exercise in a class once.

Comment: Amazingly, the sequence is in the OEIS, http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A112090

Comment: That sounds pretty awesome! 

Comment: @Qiaochu - Nah, really?  Maybe as one of those impossible bonus questions or something.

Comment: Could you give an example in degree 7 of one of the exceptional cases?

Answer (score 23):

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then any two components of the projective closure of $\text{Spec } k[x, y]/(f(x, y))$ intersect by Bezout's theorem, and one can check for the existence of such points by looking at where the partial derivatives simultaneously vanish (the singular points).  For example, $f(x, y) = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 1$ has projective closure defined by $F(X, Y, Z) = X^2 + 2XY + Y^2 - Z^2$ and the partial derivatives vanish at $(1 : -1 : 0)$, the intersection of the components $X + Y - Z = 0$ and $X + Y + Z = 0$.

Generically, $k[x]$ is a UFD, so Eisenstein's criterion applies, although I am not sure how practical this is.

Answer (score 22):

Quite a useful result can be found in Schmidt's lecture notes on *Equations over finite fields* (Theorem III.1B in SLNM 536). Suppose that $K$ is any field and let $f(x,y)=c_0y^d+c_1(x)y^{d-1}+
\cdots+c_d(x) \in K[x,y]$, with $c_0 \neq 0$.  Let 
$$
\psi(f)=\sup_{1\leq
i\leq d}\frac{\deg c_i}{i}.
$$
Then $f$ is absolutely irreducible over $K$ provided that that $\psi(f)=m/d$ with $\gcd(m,d)=1$.

This shows, for example, that the polynomial $f(x,y)=g(x)-h(y)$ is irreducible when  $\deg g$ and $\deg h$ are coprime.

Comment: Tim B! Welcome!

Answer (score 14):

Let $f\in A[x][y]$ where $A$ is a UFD and assume that $f$ is monic, i.e that it can be written as
$$
f=a_0+a_1 y+\ldots a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+y^n,
$$
with $a_i\in A[x]$. Assume that there exists an irreducible polynomial $g\in A[x]$ such that
$g|a_i$ for $i=0\ldots n-1$ and $g^2\nmid a_0$ then by Eisenstein's criterion $f$ is irreducible over $A[x]$ and therefore irreducible in $A[x,y]$. I've used the fact that $A$ was a UFD only to make sure that $gA[x]$ in $A[x]$ is a prime ideal. (Of course Eisenstein criterion is a very special case which fits within the method of the Newton polygon).

Using this idea and induction it is easy to see that polynomials like
$$
(*)\;\;\;\;  x_1^{n_1}+x_2^{n_2}+\ldots x_r^{n_r}\in \mathbf{C}[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_r],
$$
are irreducible whenever $n_i\geq 1$ and $r\geq 3$, since the polynomial $x_1^{n_1}+x_2^{n_2}$
has always a multiplicity one irreducible divisor.

More generally there is the so called Ehrenfeucht criterion which says that
$$
(**) \;\;\;\; f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+\ldots f_r(x_r)\in\mathbf{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_r],
$$
is always irreducible if $\deg(f_i)\geq 1$ and $r\geq 3$. In the case where $r=2$ 
it is still irreducible if one has $(\deg(f_1),\deg(f_2))=1$.

Note that the polynomials in $(\star)$ are a very special case of polynomials in $(\star\star)$. A nice
proof of this criterion may be found in a paper of Tverberg entitled "A remark on Ehrenfeucht's criterion for irreducibility of polynomials". Unfortunately, if you have a polynomial with mixed monomials then this criterion does not apply.

Comment: Dear Hugo, thanks for this amazing answer, but I don't have access to Tverberg's paper. Would you be so kind as providing a copy ?

Comment: Dear Georges, have a look at the following http://www.mat.ulaval.ca/fileadmin/mat/documents/Chapdelaine/Algebre_III/Notes_2015.pdf

Comment: Have a look at p. 116 of the document above. I only rewrote  Ehrenfeucht's proof with a few more details. I can send you the original paper tomorrow, if you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reprint and your fantastic notes, dear Hugo. You write "Nous aimerions maintenant présenter un critère peu connu qui nous garantit qu’un polynôme à plusieurs variables est irréductible" . *"Peu connu"* indeed!  This must be the only elementary algebra course in the universe mentioning Ehrenfeucht's result  :-) Congratulations and thank you very much again for teaching us users such beautiful and completely underappreciated mathematics.

Answer (score 13):

I have a reference for the method mentioned by David Speyer above (sorry couldn't find how to add comment to existing answer):

S. Gao, Absolute irreducibility of polynomials via newton polytopes, [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.5311)

> *Gao, Shuhong*, [**Absolute irreducibility of polynomials via Newton polytopes**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2000.8586), J. Algebra 237, No. 2, 501-520 (2001). [ZBL0997.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0997.12001). [MR1816701](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1816701)

Answer (score 10):

I think there must be a lot of work on irreducibility criteria, although I have unfortunately never seen anything like a unified treatment.

The first thing that my MathSciNet search turned up was:

---

Ayad, Mohamed
Sur les polynômes $f(X,Y)$ tels que $K[f]$ est intégralement fermé dans $K[X,Y]$. (French) [Polynomials $f(X,Y)$ such that $K(f)$ is integrally closed in $K[X,Y]$]
Acta Arith. 105 (2002), no. 1, 9--28.

MathSciNet review by Maurice Mignotte:

As indicated in the title, the author studies polynomials $f(X,Y)$ such that $K[f]$ is integrally closed in $K[X,Y]$ (then $f$ is said to be closed), where $K$ is of characteristic zero. His main result is the following theorem. Let $f(X,Y)$ be a nonconstant polynomial in $K[X,Y]$. Then $K[f]$ is integrally closed in $K[X,Y]$ if and only if there exists $a\in K$ such that $f(X,Y)+a$ is irreducible over the algebraic closure of $K$.

Indeed, this article contains many other results and also provides a survey of this question. In particular, several examples of families of closed polynomials are given. The case of positive characteristic is studied briefly at the end of the paper.

---

Explanation for how I found this: I recalled that my colleague Dino Lorenzini has a paper "Reducibility of polynomials in two variables" (J. Algebra, 1993).  Upon inspection, this paper didn't seem quite in the spirit of your question -- rather, he gives upper bounds on the number of irreducible components in certain families of polynomials -- but it has several citations on MathSciNet.  Ayad's paper is the first.

Comment: Thanks Pete! I a bit confused on how can we apply the above theorem.Let's say I start with a polynomial $f$, and I want to know whether $f$ is irreducible (not whether I can add $a$ to make it irreducible). How does the Theorem help? Am I missing something? 

Comment: So far as I can see, it does not help directly with the irreducibility of $f$; it's just an interesting result about irreducibility of polynomials in two variables.  (The other responses are definitely better...)

Answer (score 3):

there is a theorem of Ruppert, but I don't know it is useful or not. You can try: 
[pdf - arXiv:math/9808021v1 [math.NT] 5 Aug 1998](http://pdf%20-%20arXiv%3amath/9808021v1%20%5Bmath.NT%5D%205%20Aug%201998)

Comment: Dear viethung, your link sems broken.

Comment: @Georges I think https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808021 is what's wanted.

Comment: Thank you, @Gerry.

Answer (score 3):

What follows is more a series of considerations than a practical algorithm, but could still be of interest. The main idea is that it's easier to work with one-variable polynoms, so we trade a bad problem in two variables for several bad problems in one variable.

The key point is the following lemma (assume $k$ is of characteristic zero!): if $P(X,Y)$ is a two-variable polynom and there are enough distinct values of $a$ such that $P(X,a)$ is a constant polynomial, then $P(X,Y)$ is a polynom in $Y$ only. The proof is by arguing that $P(X,a)$ being a constant polynom means that $a$ is a root for the polynom (in $Y$) coefficient of $X^n$ for all $n>0$. And that can't happen too often in characteristic zero, unless those coefficients are zero polynoms, hence $P(X,Y)$ is reduced to its constant term as a polynom in $X$, hence is only a polynom in $Y$, as was to be proved.

Now, for your question : if you suppose a $P(X,Y)$ isn't irreducible, say factors as $Q(X,Y)R(X,Y)$, but many $P(X,a)$ are irreductible, then that means for each such $a$ either $Q(X,a)$ or $R(X,a)$ is a constant, hence given enough of those $a$, one of $Q$ or $R$ at least is only a polynom in $Y$ by the lemma, say $R$.

Then if you manage to fully factor $P(a,Y)=Q(a,Y)R(Y)$ for some $a$ (again dropping to a one-variable polynom), you get a list with $R$  (and divisors of $R$): check each element for divisibility of $P(X,Y)$. If none is good, $P$ is irreducible.

EDIT:

1. In fact, after you have found $R$ is a polynom in $Y$, just consider the gcd of the coefficients of the $X^n$ -- if you get $1$, $P$ is irreducible.
2. The previous considerations mostly prove that a cheating polynom (ie: not irreducible although it appears to be when evaluated along a variable) necessarily has a very precise form, which makes it susceptible to easy factorisation.