# Are there any good computer programs for drawing (algebraic) curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I realise that I lack some intuition into how a curve (or surface, or whatever) looks geometrically, from just looking at the equation. Thus, I sometimes resort to some computer program (such as *Mathematica*) to draw me a picture. The problem is, all these programs require input of the form $y=f(x)$, whereas my curve might be something like $y^3+x^3-6x^2 y=0$, and transforming this into the former form is not always easy, and always misses some information. So, my question:

Are there any programs that can take an equation ($p(x,y)=0$, say) as input and return a graph of its zero-set?

**Update:** So, lots of good answers, I wish I could accept them all. I'll accept Jack Huizenga's answer, for the reason of personal bias that I already have Mathematica available.

Comment: Cinderella.$   $

Comment: [offtop] Your curve is a union of lines, because polynomial is homogeneous. You can just denote by $a_i$ solutions of $y^3+1-6y=0$ and write $y^3+x^3-6 x^2y=(y-a_1 x)(y-a_2 x)(y-a_3 x)$.[/offtop]

Comment: If you have access to Mathematica and it produces the diagram you want, fine, but for more control use gnuplot+tikz.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mathematica does this just fine.  You're looking for the command ContourPlot, as in

ContourPlot[y^3+x^3-6x^2y==0,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}].

A more serious issue is that if you're trying to do algebraic geometry over $\mathbb C$, the real picture isn't always terribly enlightening.

Comment: The bright side is that the real picture may be easy to draw: think of $x^2+y^2+1=0$ ... 

Comment: And of course, in the example Ketil posted, the curve is just a union of three lines, all meeting at the origin.  I agree real pictures are definitely worth something, especially when first cutting your teeth with the material.

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about. I would have no idea that this curve was a union of lines, just by looking at it.

Comment: That is, by looking at the equation, obviously...

Comment: Actually, with a bit more experience, its quite easy to see that.  Any homogeneous polynomial in 2 variables factors as a product of linear forms over $\mathbb C$; it's also not hard to see that these complex lines intersect the real plane in real lines.

Comment: Downvoted because there are free and open source alternatives which solve this problem.

Comment: Mathematica is "freely" available to most people who post on this site, and the original poster demonstrated he was already familiar with and had access to Mathematica.

Comment: If I could accept multiple answers, I would have. This answer got the nod because it solved my immediate problem, but it might as well have been Julián Aguirre's answer, as SAGE is on my list of things I should get around to looking at, but haven't yet. Mathematica is 'free' in the sense that my university has it installed on its systems, but I agree that open-source alternatives should be encouraged.

Answer (score 25):

[SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/): The free open-source mathematical software SAGE can also do what you want.

Comment: Here's how to do this in Sage:

var('x,y'); contour_plot(y^3+x^3-6*x^2*y==0, (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3))

Answer (score 13):

I can also recommend "surf" http://surf.sourceforge.net/ and the nice graphical user interface "surfex" http://www.surfex.algebraicsurface.net/ by Oliver Labs and Stephan Holzer.

This program produces really nice renders of algebraic surfaces (and curves).
Check out http://www.algebraicsurface.net/ for examples.
Some of you might also remember the old covers of the Suse Linux distribution.
Those were made with this programs.

Answer (score 6):

I really like [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/). There's also [Jep Implicit Plotter](http://www.singsurf.org/djep/ImplicitPlot.php), which is interactive.

Wolfram Alpha understands Mathematica syntax and is free. The example given is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5By%5E3%2Bx%5E3-6x%5E2y%3D%3D0%2C%7Bx%2C-5%2C5%7D%2C%7By%2C-5%2C5%7D%5D

Comment: GrafEq is awesome. It can even see if your algebraic curve has isolated points!

Comment: Yes, GrafEq uses robust, interval methods.

Answer (score 5):

The mathematical visualization program 3D-XplorMath (which is freely available at http://3D-XplorMath.org) will do this easily. When the program starts up, first select the "Plane Curve" category, then select the "User Implicit" object, and then just enter your polynomial $p(x,y)$ in the "User-2D Curve" Dialog and click the Create button.

Answer (score 4):

The software packages  [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) can also do this.  An example for $y^3 + x^3 - 6x^2y=0$ would be as follows.  Change the last line from contour(z) to surf(z) to get a surface plot; to surfl(z) to get a shaded and illuminated surface plot.

```
xmin=-5.0; xstep=0.1; xmax=5.0; // replace with your values
ymin=.... ;                     // replace with your values
// // generate x,y lattice points for plot
[x y]=meshgrid(xmin:xstep:xmax, ymin:ystep:ymax);
// // define z=f(x,y), replace with your desired function
z=y.^3 + x.^3 - 6 * x.^2 .* y;
// // now perform contour plot of function
contour(z);
// or surf(z), or surfl(z) for surface plots
```

and Octave and Scilab are free software and open-source software which can be freely downloaded and used on multiple operating system platforms.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab --  http://www.scilab.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave --   http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

If you've got a Macintosh with OS X, or System 9, you can use the built in [Graphing Calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) program [NuCalc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuCalc) to directly type in the equation, zoom in and out, and fly around the 3-d surface plot;  Graphing Calculator can also do inequalitiies such as $x^2+y^2 \gt 5$.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else is looking to this for advice, I'll add that Maple can also do this. The algcurves package has the command plot_real_curve(f,x,y,options) where f is your curve and x and y are the variables you use.

The benefit of this package is the default plot includes all 'interesting' points, and won't let you miss out.

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=algcurves/plot_real_curve

Answer (score 4):

In [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), you can do this by (ab)using the 3D contour plot feature.

```
gnuplot> f(x,y) = x**2+y**2-1
gnuplot> set contour
gnuplot> set cntrparam levels discrete 0
gnuplot> set view 0,0
gnuplot> unset surface
gnuplot> splot f(x,y)
```

You can get a smoother curve by doing something like

```
gnuplot> set isosamples 500,500
gnuplot> replot
```

Answer (score 3):

For high quality pictures of surfaces like [these](http://www.freigeist.cc/gallery.html), Herwig Hauser apparently uses [povray](http://povray.org/).
It's not really what you're asking for and probably overkill, but I thought I'll add it for the record.

Answer (score 0):

[DMelt](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) has good plotting capabilities, with possibility to export math drawings in the vector graphics format (SVG, EPS, PDF). I would recommend to look at jhplot.HPlot3D JAVA class to draw jhplot.F2D functions