# Integral points on a particular family of curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211963/when-is-the-image-of-an-integral-polynomial-contained-in-the-image-of-another) (and comments thereon). Namely, it follows from Felipe Voloch's comment that for any $n>2$ there is a finite set of integral $(x, y),$ such that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(x+i) = n y^2.$$
The question is: is there any $n$ for which the explicit list is known (and if so, how it was generated)? I would assume that $n=3, 4$ should be tractable...

**ADDENDUM** In joro's answer he points out that for $n=3$ there are no nontrivial solutions. For $n=4,$ sage computes the Weierstrass form of the curve as
$$y^2 = x^3 - 208/3*x + 4480/27.$$
It then finds that the rank of the MW group is $0,$ and that the torsion subgroup is of the form $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.$ The generators are claimed to be $(-4/3: 16:1)$ and $(8/3:0:1).$ I assume this is for the transformed $x, y,$ so I am not sure what this means for the integral solutions - I am sure someone here does, though...

Comment: Regarding the addendum: For $n = 4$, there are no non-trivial ($y \neq 0$) integer solutions, by the Erdos-Selfridge result that I quoted.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Oops, forgot that $4$ was a square :), thanks! But still, can you parse what the sage result actually means?

Comment: I do not know if I can read the conclusion of no other integral solutions without actually computing all seven non-trivial points of the transformed equation, as well as the change of coordinates map. In any case, we know that four of these seven non-identity rational points were given as $y = 0$ and $x \in \{-1,\ldots,-4\}$ in the original coordinates.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Yes, exactly. But what about those four other mysterious points.

Comment: Well, one of them is just the point $[0:1:0]$ at infinity, which is the neutral element. So there are three more.

Comment: For a hyperelliptic curve $y^{2} = f(x)$, where $f(x)$ has even degree, there are two points at infinity on the non-singular model. In addition, there are the points $(-5/2,3/2)$ and $(-5/2,-3/2)$. This explains the four points other than those with $y = 0$.

Comment: I edited my answer for the case $n=4$ giving map to the original curve.

Answer (score 7):

Erdos and Selfridge have proved that the product of two or more consecutive non-zero integers is never a power (*Illinois J. Math,* vol. **19**, no. 2, 1975). This implies in particular that for $n > 1$ a perfect square, the only integer solutions are the ones given by $y =0$ and $x \in \{-1,\ldots,-n\}$. The proof of the Erdos-Selfridge theorem is elementary and very clever, based on Sylvester's theorem: *For $n > k$, the product $(n+1) \cdots (n+k)$ has at least one prime factor exceeding $k$*. It is possible that the method might extend to certain other values of $n$. A related but simpler problem was the determination of all perfect power binomial coefficients, solved similarly by Erdos in 1951 and included in the collection *Proofs from the Book*.

In the general case it may be asking too much to have a complete description of the triples $(x,y,n)$. But for any hyperelliptic equation $dy^2 = f(x)$, the determination of all integer solutions $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ is at least in theory possible by Alan Baker's estimates for logarithmic linear forms, and a finite search. Siegel had explained how to reduce the hyperelliptic to a finite set of two-variable $S$-unit equations, see section 5.3.4 from Bombieri and Gubler (*Heights in Diophantine Geometry*) for the structure of this argument. Then Baker's theorem applies straightforwardly. This allows in principle allowing to determine all solutions $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any given value $n$.

Comment: Actually, Erd\H{o}s and Selfridge proved something stronger, that implies that the equation $$\prod_{i=1}^n (x+i)=b y^2$$ has no solutions with $n \geq 4$, $x > n^2$ and $b$ an integer with greatest prime factor $< n$. This was extended by Saradha and Shorey to $n=3$ and to the greatest prime factor of $b$ being $\leq n$. In the $n=3$ case, one gets a single solution corresponding to $(x,b,y)=(47,6,140)$.

Answer (score 5):

The $n = 5$ case gives the hyperelliptic curve $C : y^{2} = 5x^{5} - 25x^{3} + 20x$. The Jacobian $J$ has $J(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{4}$ and a generator of the infinite part is $\infty - (4,60)$. Using this, the method of Chabauty proves that the only rational points on $C' : y^{2} = 5(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)$ are the point at infinity, those with $y = 0$ and also $x = 1$, $y = \pm 60$.

The same sort of argument works for the $n = 6$ case.

Comment: Ah, so this is actually the first nontrivial example!

Comment: Maybe easier for $n=6$, because there the curve is bielliptic [involution $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (7-x,y)$] and it's easier to compute ranks of two elliptic curves than one genus-2 Jacobian.  There's also an elliptic quotient for $n=8$.

Answer (score 2):

The case $n=3$ leads to the elliptic curve in Weierstrass form $u^3  - 9u = v^2$.

The map is $(x,y) =( u/3 - 2, v/9) $.

It has finite number of rational points and none of them leads to solution other than $y=0$.

One way to find the Weirstrass form is in Maple:

```
with(algcurves);Weierstrassform( (x+1)*(x+2)*(x+3)-3*y^2,x,y,u,v);
```

---

**Added** Extending Igor Rivin's answer about $n=4$.

The Weierstrass form is rank zero, so we must map the torsion points
to the original curve and check for integrality.

The $x$ coordinate on the original curve is $-1/2*(-24*u+208)/(-3*u+44)$

Comment: How do you find the rational points? Does Maple do that too?

Comment: @IgorRivin Don't know how to to do this in Maple, but it is possible in sage. If the rank is zero, all rational points are given by: `E.torsion_points()`

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out in sage, but how did you get the transform to the Weierstrass form? From your typesetting, I assume that this is something Sage did, but how?

Comment: @IgorRivin maybe sage can did the first form, but the second Weierstrass form was from Maple. I have sage code quartic with rational point to Weierstrass form, but didn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The following idea may work for some not too large fixed $n.$ E.g. let $n=7.$ The equation has the following form $$(x+4)(x^2+8x+7)(x^2+8x+12)(x^2+8x+15)=7y^2.$$ It remains to check the possible $\gcd$ values. As far as I see one obtains that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+4)(x^2+8x+7)&=&7\delta\square,\\
(x^2+8x+12)(x^2+8x+15)&=&\delta\square,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\delta\mid 160$ or
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+4)(x^2+8x+7)&=&\delta\square,\\
(x^2+8x+12)(x^2+8x+15)&=&7\delta\square,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\delta\mid 160.$
That is the problem is reduced to determine integral points on certain elliptic curves.

As Elkies already noted the case $n=8$ leads to elliptic curves. One obtains that $$8(X+8)(X+14)(X+18)(X+20)=y^2,$$ where $X=x^2+9x.$ Using the MAGMA procedure

IntegralQuarticPoints([8,480,10464,97408,322560],[-8,0]);

the list of integral points is as follows:
[
    [ -26, 288 ],
    [ -38, -1440 ],
    [ -14, 0 ],
    [ -20,0],[ -8,0],                                                                         [ -18, 0],                                                                             [ -16, -32]]. It remains to solve the equations $x^2+9x=x_0,$ where $x_0$ is an $x$-coordinate of an integral point. There are only trivial solutions, that is $x\in\{-8,-7,\ldots,-1\}.$

Comment: That's a nice idea, and the computation you mention give a boost to the idea that there is a high likelihood of only trivial solutions.