# Factorization of polynomials in two variables

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

I have read, from the question
[Irreducibility of  polynomials in two variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables?lq=1), that all polynomials $f(x)-g(y)$, where $f, g$ are indecomposable polynomials, and there are no $a, b$ such that $g(ax+b)=f(x)$, are irreducible, unless the degrees of $f$ and $g$ are $$7, 11, 13, 15, 21,\ \  \text{or} \ \  31$$

Is there an example of the exceptional case in degree $7$, with the factorization?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An example for $n=7$ is given in  J. W. S. Cassels, Factorization of polynomials in several variables, Proc. Fifteenth Scandinavian Congress (Oslo, 1968), vol. 118, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Springer, Berlin, pp. 1-17. This reference is from https://oeis.org/A112090 and is quite technical (using topology of Riemann surfaces).

here I type the example from the paper in a sort of computer-readable format

```
l=(1+sqrt(-7))/2
m=(1-sqrt(-7))/2
# t a nonzero(?) parameter
f(x)-g(y)=(x^3+l*x^3*y-m*x*y^2-y^3-(3*l+2)*t*x+(3*m+2)*t*y+t)*
          (x^4-l*x^3*y-x^2*y^2-m*x*y^3+y^4+2*(m-l)*t*x^2-
           7*t*x*y+2*(l-m)*t*y^2+(3-l)*t*x-(3-m)*t*y-7*t^2)
```

Sage script (with input f and (-)g taken from the paper

```
z=QQ['z'].0
K.<l>=NumberField(z^2-z+2)
m=l.conjugate()
R.<x,y,t>=K[]
# t a nonzero(?) parameter
f=x^7-7*l*t*x^5+(4-l)*t*x^4+(14*l-35)*t^2*x^3-(8*l+10)*t^2*x^2+(3-l+7*(3*l+2)*t)*t^2*x
g=-y^7+7*m*t*y^5+(4-m)*t*y^4-(14*m-35)*t^2*y^3-(8*m+10)*t^2*y^2-(3-m+7*(3*m+2)*t)*t^2*y-7*t^3
(f+g).factor()
```

outputs

```
(x^3 + (l)*x^2*y + (l - 1)*x*y^2 - y^3 + (-3*l - 2)*x*t + (-3*l + 5)*y*t + t) * 
(x^4 + (-l)*x^3*y - x^2*y^2 + (l - 1)*x*y^3 + y^4 + (-4*l+2)*x^2*t-
 7*x*y*t + (4*l-2)*y^2*t + (-l + 3)*x*t + (-l-2)*y*t - 7*t^2)
```

which is the factorisation that should be like the one above.
But it is not - there is a typo above (and in the paper: in the 1st factor the monomial l*x^3*y should be l*x^2*y. After this change everything checks out.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to find a copy of that paper, but they all seem to be in some journal.

Comment: I can email you a copy - but in your profile contact details are missing...

Comment: Is typo in your formula possible? After expanding the factorization and fixing $t$ I have $(-16*w1 - 20)*x^3*y$ for w1=sqrt(-7).

Comment: @joro : please see my latest edit.

Comment: I agree with the sage code. Maybe my mistake, but I am not sure the factorization is equal to the first formula.

Comment: I should have created K with l being a primitive element, it would have been easier to spot the difference

Comment: OK, I agree with the sage formula but not sure the first formula is correct. Do you still claim the first formula is correct? (I tried to verify it via essentially yours approach and used the same number field).

Comment: I copied the 1st formula from the paper,as best as I could. Perhaps it was not correct there. I'll have a look.

Comment: ok, indeed there is a typo in the paper.

Comment: my email is tcblok@gmail.com

Comment: ok, just sent it.